# I get error when I want to execute my program from /home

Tags: ubuntu, autostart

I have compiled my code in this path : `/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC` and created executable file `myapp` .

I can run it from inside the `SRC` folder like `./myapp`. But when I try `/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC/myapp` from my `/home/m` it gives me:

```
   in cs_init.txt at 0: 
    Error opening utf8writeappend file LOGS/startlog.txt: No such file or directory
```

Why do I get this error message?

My main problem is that, I want to build a kiosk like system and want to add my executable file inside : `/home/m/.config/openbox/autostart` like this:

```
$ cat /home/m/.config/openbox/autostart 
echo 7 > /tmp/yy
/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC/myapp &
echo 8 > /tmp/yy2
```

But it doesn't work!
I could do it already with other programs, but this program gives me this error!

NOTE: There are some folders inside `ChatScript-master` directory like `SRC` and `LOGS` and my executable file is inside `SRC` folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program uses a relative path from the current working directory to access `LOGS/startlog.txt`.  If there is no `LOGS` directory in the current directory, the application fails.

To correct this, make sure that the application uses an absolute path for accessing the file, or change the working directory as you start the application:

```
( cd /home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC && ./myapp ) &
```

... assuming `/home/m/ChatScript-master/SRC` contains the needed `LOGS` directory.

Comment: `LOGS` folder is beside the `SRC` folder inside `ChatScript-master`

Comment: @Hasani Well then the current working directory probably needs to be `/home/m/ChatScript-master`.

Comment: @Hasani Or, the application changes its own working directory. It's hard for me to know. Does my suggestion work at all?

Comment: No, unfortunately it didn't work :(

Comment: `ChatScript-master` folder has some folders like `SRC` and `LOGS`. And inside the `SRC` is my executable file `myapp`. I can run `myapp` from inside the SRC` folder, but your suggestion didn't work

Comment: Does `cd /home/m/ChatScript-master && ./SRC/myapp` work?

Comment: @Hasani This is most peculiar. Does the application depend on any environment variables?

Comment: @Kusalananda: no

Comment: @Hasani Is there a configuration file that contains paths to directories etc.?

Comment: I don't know, I couldn't find such file

Comment: @Hasani The error message mentions `cs_init.txt`, that's why I asked.

Comment: @Kusalananda: I couldn't find that file but your second suggestion worked! (although I added `&` at the end of it)

Comment: @Hasani I'm still slightly mystified why running it from `SRC` did not work in the script, but I'm happy you got it working somehow!